intellij IDE with cursive index 0 out of bounds for length 0
I'm trying to setup intellij ultimate with cursive. When I try to refresh/load leiningen project, i get an cryptic error notification on the bottom right corner: "index 0 out of bounds for length 0"
I'm actually not sure if this is an issue with cursive or leiningen, but i am unable to load/run clojure due to this issue.
